# How to get "fixed" position of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get an element's position relative to the window (fixed position).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.fixedPosition = function () {
        var offset = this.offset();
        var $doc = $(document);
        return {
            'x': offset.left - $doc.scrollLeft(),
            'y': offset.top - $doc.scrollTop()
        };
    };
})(jQuery);

$('#thumbnails img').click(function () {
    var pos = $(this).fixedPosition();
    console.log(pos);
});
```

But when I click a thumbnail, it appears to be off by about 10 pixels or so. i.e., it will give me negative values for `y` even when the top edge of the photo is about 5 pixels away from the top of my browser window.

Comment: Copied your code on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/qZa5z/ Atleast for HTML elements (input), it is displaying correct values. Can you check with images?

Comment: @SandeepGB: http://jsfiddle.net/qZa5z/1/ Seems to work with images too...

Comment: Why do you not use the css property position:fixed ?

Comment: @CharlesJourdan: I'm taking a relatively-positioned element and animating it into fixed-position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**

Solution now depends on [JSizes](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jsizes/) and a couple helper methods:

```
function Point(x, y) {
    return {
        'x': x,
        'y': y,
        'left': x,
        'top': y
    };
}

$.fn.outerOffset = function () {
    /// <summary>Returns an element's offset relative to its outer size; i.e., the sum of its left and top margin, padding, and border.</summary>
    /// <returns type="Object">Outer offset</returns>
    var margin = this.margin();
    var padding = this.padding();
    var border = this.border();
    return Point(
        margin.left + padding.left + border.left,
        margin.top + padding.top + border.top
    );
};


$.fn.fixedPosition = function () {
    /// <summary>Returns the "fixed" position of the element; i.e., the position relative to the browser window.</summary>
    /// <returns type="Object">Object with 'x' and 'y' properties.</returns>
    var offset = this.offset();
    var $doc = $(document);
    var bodyOffset = $(document.body).outerOffset();
    return Point(offset.left - $doc.scrollLeft() + bodyOffset.left, offset.top - $doc.scrollTop() + bodyOffset.top);
};
```

Comment: Arghhh! `$(document.body).position()` reports as `-20` in Firefox instead of `-10`! Where's that extra 10 coming from?

Comment: Why go against the grain? Just remove all padding, margin, and borders from the body. If you need a black stripe across the top of the page, just use a div with a background. :) .offset() should be accurate cross-browser in that case.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte: I suppose I could.. I just don't like the idea of it not working under certain scenarios, but I guess I'm not really planning on releasing this as a library.

Comment: I totally agree, it's annoying that it doesn't auto-account for body attributes. Gotta love cross-browser DOM issues. :/

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
element.getBoundingClientRect();
```

In a JQuery Plugin:

```
$.fn.fixedPosition = function () {
    var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: rect.left,
        y: rect.top
    };
};
```

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMClientRect

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine and it should work as you're expecting it to.

That said, .offset() has a "gotcha" involved in which it won't account for any padding, margin, or border applied to the DOM body. It finds the offset of the element in relation to the document, not the window.

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

From the documentation:

> Note: jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the body element.

Some css should hopefully fix the weird results:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; }
```

Comment: I've set my margin and padding to 0, but I'm still experiencing the problem on my site. I'm trying to recreate the issue in a fiddle, but no luck so far.

Comment: Here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/xGy4N/ it's something else in the CSS...not sure what though.

Comment: It's that black 10px border-top. :)

Comment: Doh! Didn't even notice I had a border. Is there no way to compensate for that?

Comment: Well you have two options. If this is a one-off method you're writing for your own stuff, just subtract 10 from your fixedPosition method. If this is something you want to distribute or share, you should write a method to account any potential css values that could mess with the offset.

Comment: Well yes, but I was asking for an easy way to determine how much it was off by, but I figured it out :-)